# Mapping not working use "async" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, async-await, mapping, future

I'm trying to add "async" in my generated "mapping" from firebase in flutter

```
...data.docs.map(
            (doc) async { // here I try to add async, but it doesn't work
              Map<String, dynamic> dt = doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              print("Oy");
              number++;
              dataCostumer.value = await getCostumer("${dt['id_customer']}");
              return pw.TableRow(
                children: [
                  pw.Expanded(
                    child: pw.Text("$number", textAlign: tCenter),
                  ),
                  pw.Expanded(
                    child: pw.Text("${dt['id_customer']}", textAlign: tCenter),
                  ),
                  pw.Expanded(
                    child: pw.Padding(
                      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                      child: pw.Text("${dt['id_CUSTOMER']}", textAlign: tLeft),
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.Expanded(
                    child: pw.Text('Analog', textAlign: tCenter),
                  ),
                  pw.Expanded(
                    child: pw.Text('01-01-2023', textAlign: tCenter),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
```

I tried using await inside the mapping, but it didn't work. I've tried a few things like Future.wait() but it doesn't work, I've also tried casting it but it doesn't work either. Is there anything I can try or is there something I should change??

Comment: the problem is that you're trying to make the map asynchronous, and its sychronous

Comment: try iterating over your `docs` using a `for loop` combined with `async`/`await`

Comment: Using `Iterable.map` with an asynchronous callback will result in an `Iterable` of `Future`s.  *How* did you use `Future.wait`?  Did you use it with a `FutureBuilder`?